# Recursive Map in R

Tags: r, functional-programming

I'm trying to find or write a function related to Map() in R that generates a nested list of results upon applying a function.

The R Map() function runs as follows:

```
Map(f, v, w, x)
=> list(
       f(v1, w1, x1),
       f(v2, w2, x2), ...)
```

I'd like to Map the function over every combination of arguments in v, w, x, etc and return a list - the top level of the list corresponding to the entries in v, each of these entries should be a list and contain entries for each level of w, and on ...

In code, I'd want

```
Map_recursive(f, v) == Map(f, v) == lapply(v, f)
# 
# Map_recursive(c, c(a1=1, a2=2)) 
# => List(a1 = 1, a2 = 2)

Map_recursive(f, v, w) 
== Map(function(vi) {
    Map(f, vi, w)
    }, v)
== lapply(v, function(vi){
    lapply(w, function(wi) f(vi, wi))
  })
#
# Map_recursive(c, c(a1 = 1, a2 = 2), c(b1=10, b2 = 20, b3 = 30))
# => List(
#      a1 = List(b1 = (1, 10), b2 = (1, 20), b3 = (1, 30)),
#      a2 = List(b1 = (2, 10), b2 = (2, 20), b3 = (2, 30))
#      )

Map_recursive(f, v, w, x) == Map(function(vi){
    Map(function(wj){
        Map(f, vi, wj, x)
        }, w)},
    v
    )
# ... all the way down
```

Importantly, unlike in Map, the iterable inputs shouldn't need to have the same length (ie, v, w, x can have different lengths) and different numbers of iterable inputs should be possible.

I've searched through things like R::purrr and R::functional but I couldn't find a higher-order function that does what I need

R

Comment: Why do you want to do it recursively, and how does this differ from functions in the `apply` family which are R's version(s) of `map`?

Comment: The only way I could see to use that family of functions to do what I wanted was to nest lapply calls inside each other, which is pretty ugly, and has to be hard-coded to work with different numbers of iterables

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear but it is starting to make sense. Is the `f` in question supposed to apply to atomic types and `v`, `w` etc. nested lists with the same degree of nesting (e.g. representing trees) and then you are looking for a map function which will take a collection of e.g. parallel trees and return a tree of the same structure obtained by applying `f` to the leaves?

Answer (score 1):

Please disregard this question. For my current purposes I was able to solve the problem as follows, (although I have to strictly order the arguments to f):

```
Map_recursive <- function(f, ...){
  require(purrr)
  dots <- list(...)
  if (length(dots) == 1){
    return(
      do.call("Map", args = append(list(f), dots))
      )
    } else {
    Map(
      function(vi){
        new.f <- purrr::partial(f, vi)
        do.call(
          "Map_recursive",
          args = append(list(new.f), dots[-1])
          )
        },
      dots[[1]]
      )
    }
  }
```